# How many people should participate in a content audit?

Tags: content, content-audit

We're the in the early stages of a complete redesign of our corporate website. Content audit is first, and I started putting together a plan.

My question: how many (and what are the job titles) should contribute to the audit? Are there good/bad things about having too many people? I assumed myself (UX specialist) and the PM are the people who should do it, but the PM wants about 4 other stakeholders to do it as well and we combine data in the end. Should everyone look at everything? Is this good or bad? We only have 50 - 60 pages, so it's not a logistics problem. If it's bad, how can I convince her otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete site redesign is a huge opportunity. I would start by IGNORING what you have going on your current site. Spend 20 minutes staring into a mirror in an attempt to hypnotize yourself into forgetting that you know anything about it. Start by defining the flows and messages for each key audience.

**Audiences**  Put together a list of key constituencies. Customer groups, audiences, markets and partners. This usually includes: Existing Customers, New Customers, Stale customers, one-off Product Buyers, Media, Talent/popential Hires, Partners, Investors, etc.

**Vision** Interview the people who represent the vision of the company. This includes all the senior management. Here is a checklist of Q's You can ask the same questions different ways.

**a. What is the company valued for? 

b. what are our sustainable points of differentiation?  

c. What do we do? (seriously - ask this)  

d. Why do we do that? (Apple makes computers, they make them in order to make things    incredibly great to use) - you need to find the WHY  Specifically,for each product type. 

e. How do we deliver ? 

f. Establish points of credibility for the value proposition (features etc.)**

**Content** Now, you need to work out how to get the informaton from a-f into a context  that connects with the problem you solve for each constituency. I would also look to defining the selling sequence, in general prioritizing the information for your information architecture.

Seriously, this is a great opportunity to make a valuable contribution to your company- and it could afford you access to the top people in the organization. That access is needed to really do this well. You might find it interesting to record the interviews.

Now, you can revisit the existing content to see what components solve the communications challenges you have uncovered in a way that is still relevant.

**Purge and Simplify** I would encourage you to put the greatest emphasis on simplicity. Almost NOBODY is going to drag their tired eyes across much drivel about YOUR products Let them get the top level and cut anything repetitive or non-essential. Keep it real. Remove the jargon and corporate speak if you can.

**The best way to unravel this is with a story told in pictures and/or video.**

**Specifically, to answer your question** - Almost everyone could be involved to some degree. I do hope this is helpful, and not overly simplistic.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have no experience whatsoever in content auditing, but I'm a tech writer that often has to ask for feedback for customer-facing documention.

If you are redesigning a corporate site, you should start creating some personas. That will make focus on what kind of message you want to send, and what kind of customers you want to target.

For the content audit itself, I think you should involve:

- Product Manager - they should be the ones knowing what market segments the product sells to, and what are the features that make your product attractive for target customers
- Product Marketing - they are the ones that will know how to pitch the product and write juicy content that might call the attention of your customers
- Pre-Sales -  they are the ones listening to the customers frequent questions. If lots of customers are doing the same question you might pitch the product in a way that these questions are addressed heads-on. Less questions leads to a fastest sales cycle.

I don't think everyone should revise everything. If you have a good information architecture in place, it will be easier to understand who should be responsible for revising what.
If everyone is responsible for everything, it might be difficult to make all parties agree on something. So all pieces of content should have several stakeholders, but a single person/team should be responsible for it. This means that if you can't get anyone to agree with it, someone can easily make a final decision.

My advise would also be to align these stakeholders before presenting a proposal to senior management. This will allow you to mature your ideas and build a solid redesign that every one on the team agrees and can defend when senior management starts providing feedback.

Comment: Good point here @jff - "If everyone is responsible for everything, it might be difficult to make all parties agree on something."